# Truly verifying the presence of an element using Java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

So I ran into something weird today.. I have a test that verifies the presence of footer elements on a homepage. I use a very basic method using the WebDriverWait(driverWait)..

```
public boolean verifyCarResearchLnkIsClickable() {
        return driverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(selector.getCarResearch())).isDisplayed();
    }
```

I then verify this in a test step using TestNG's Assert..

```
Assert.assertTrue(homePage.verifyCarResearchLnkIsClickable());
```

Today, my tests were passing but the element was not displayed on the screen. I used jquery in Chrome to see if the element could be found in the inspector and it was, but the element was not on the screen.. So what had happened was that the code I got from the inspector contained my link so thats why my tests passed but in actuality it wasnt on the screen.. What is the way to truly check for this? Is this the correct way to do it? Should this not happen, and something weird might have just happened during a build?

Answer (score 1):

`ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(loc)` checks:

- Existence of the element
- Visibility of the element, whether it is displayed
- Whether it is enabled, i.e. not actively disabled.

i.e. whether it's potentially clickable, whatever the results of that click might be. It could be a link, a button, or just a piece of static text.

Of course, rather than checking the status of the element to determine "truth", you should probably think in *functional* terms: **actually** click the element and validate the side-effects in detail.

---

The WebDriver spec [has a lot to say](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#element-displayedness) about "displayedness":

> Although WebDriver does not define a primitive to ascertain the
>   visibility of an element in the viewport, we acknowledge that it is an
>   important feature for many users. Here we include a recommended
>   approach which will give a simplified approximation of an element’s
>   visibility, but please note that it relies only on tree-traversal, and
>   only covers a subset of visibility checks.
>
> The visibility of an element is guided by what is perceptually visible
>   to the human eye. In this context, an element's displayedness does not
>   relate to the visibility or display style properties
>
> The approach recommended to implementors to ascertain an element's
>   visibility is based on crude approximations about its nature and
>   relationship in the tree. **An element is in general to be considered
>   visible if any part of it is drawn on the canvas within the bounderies (sic)
>   of the viewport.** [...]

The [low-level code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/atoms/dom.js#L672) demonstrates the actual "shown?" logic used. It looks quite complex, but the comment simply says:

> Determines whether an element is what a user would call "shown". This means
>   that the element is shown in the viewport of the browser, and only has
>   height and width greater than 0px, and that its visibility is not "hidden"
>   and its display property is not "none" [...]

In my view, none of this guarantees that the element would necessarily be visible to a pair of human eyes, but is that really important to you?

It wouldn't matter to me if I was running continuous automated tests overnight in a headless browser. I'd likely only care that clicking the element loaded the page, added the item to the cart etc., so I could verify the actual **effect**.

Comment: True, and this is the solution I feel I am going to use only because I do not see another way to do it. The only thing is, this is an automation project for a fairly large corporation and the footer contains close to 30 links.. Was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this but I suppose not. Thanks for the reply!